# Determining wattage of a variable resistor in series with a known resistor

Tags: resistors, variable

[image]

I'm trying to determine the wattage of a variable resistor Rvar which will be wired in series with a 2 ohm resistor Rs as in the above figure. Rs can handle high currents.

The power supply V1 is 24V 20A power supply.

I follow the following logic:

If Rvar is set to 0 then it disspates no power.

If Rvar is set to 10ohm it disspates I^2*R = [24/(10+2)]^2 * 10 = 40W

If Rvar is set to 6ohm it disspates I^2*R = [24/(6+2)]^2 * 6 = 54W

If Rvar is set to 2ohm it disspates I^2*R = [24/(2+2)]^2 * 2 = 72W

If Rvar is set to 1ohm it disspates I^2*R = [24/(1+2)]^2 * 1 = 64W

It seems like we need to use maximum power transfer concept which happens when Rvar = Rs when sizing the wattage of a variable resistor or a potentiometer.

So in my case I should use a variable resistor wuth 72W or more power rating?
Is my way of thinking right for variable resistors and potentiometers in such circuits?

Comment: You are not applying 24V to the pot. You need to take the max current you run through it.

Comment: but max power dissipation doesnt happen when max current passes. it happens when rs = rvar isnt it?

Comment: "Wattage" is a term used to describe the maximum rating of power of a resistor and not the actual power being dissipated.

Comment: my problem is that i wanna order such part: http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/adjustable-resistors/8924913/ but it mentions wattages not currents.

Comment: Maximum power transfer is when the load (Rvar) matches the source resistance (Rs). Therefore 72W, when the load is 2 ohm is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the 'variable resistor' is a transistor, always the same size regardless of setting, then you do need to compute the maximum power as you suggest.

If the variable resistor is a rheostat or potentiometer with a contact sliding along a track, then at different slider positions, you have different amounts of track to heat, and so different total power dissipations available.

That is why such an element is rated for the maximum **current** the track can handle.

For instance, in the datasheet of the RS part 8924913 you linked to, it says, in the characteristics section (my highlighting) ...[image]

In order to calculate the max current, use the rated max resistance and the rated max power. For instance, a 10 ohm  100 watt resistor would take sqrt(100/10) = 3.2 amps. It will now take this at any setting.

Unfortunately, the data sheet above for this part is wrong. If you don't know the physics behind, or can't mathematically invert, \$P=I^2R\$, to get current as sqrt(P/R), then you will read the data sheet as current = sqrt(P)/R, which it does strictly say, as the surd does not cover the whole fraction. This will give the wrong answer. Slap on the wrist to data sheet writer. Cautionary note to all data sheet users, sometimes equations are not type-set correctly. When in doubt, apply physics.

Comment: my problem is that i wanna order such part: uk.rs-online.com/web/p/adjustable-resistors/8924913 but it mentions wattages not currents. do u think 10 ohm 100W variable resistor is ok in my case?

Comment: im confused after reading the comments

Comment: @user16307 added de-confusing data sheet extract to the answer.

Comment: If you need the power rating instead of the current rating us P = I^2R.

Comment: OMG so if I use a 100Watt rated one. When at the lower end the wattage P becomes 10Watt and the max current becomes sqrt(10)/1ohm and at the high end the max current becomes sqrt(90)/9ohm = 1A . This is horrible for my application I was planning to pass around 5 amper throuh Rs.

Comment: If you use a 10ohm 100 watt resistor, then you calculate max current from rated max P and max R. P/R = 10, so max current = 3.16Amps, regardless of resistance setting.

Comment: i dont understand. totally confused. where does 3.16 come from?

Comment: Fok sqrt(p/r) i thought in fata sheet it is sqrt(p)/r

Comment: @user16307 adding de-confusing comment on data sheet.